# RequireJS BackBone is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

i tried these tutorials [first](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/build-backbone-apps-using-requirejs/) and [second](http://ozkatz.github.io/converting-an-existing-backbonejs-project-to-requirejs.html) and [third](http://gregfranko.com/blog/using-backbone-dot-js-with-require-dot-js/) but backbone is still not working. The console output says: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined"*

 The folder structure is:

```
index.html
   resources
      js
         b.js
         main.js
         meinmodul.js
      libs
         backbone.js
         jquery-1.7.1.js
         requireJS_2.1.5.js
         underscore.js
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>test</title>
<!--Require JS -->
<script data-main='resources/js/main' src='resources/libs/requireJS_2.1.5.js'></script</head>
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<span>Hallo!</span>
<div id='foo'>foo</div>
</div></body></html>
```

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    framework: '../libs',
    jquery:'../libs/jquery-1.7.1',
    underscore:'../libs/underscore',
    backbone:'../libs/backbone'
},

shim: {
    'underscore': {
        'exports': '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
        'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        'exports': 'Backbone'
    },
}
});
require(['jquery', 'meinmodul'], function(jq, meinmodul) {
alert('div foo is foo');
$('#foo').html('bar');
});
require(['jquery','backbone','b'], function(jq, Backbone, test) {
console.log("my backbone view");
});
```

b.js:

```
define(['jquery','backbone'], function($,Backbone) {
    var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click": 'savenow'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("init1");
        console.log($('#testid'));

    },

    savenow: function(){
        console.log("test save method");
    }
});
//return SearchView;
    return {
    'SearchView': SearchView
};
});
```

What did i miss or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed baseUrl in require.config().

If baseUrl is not set manually, all js paths are based on html path.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles